# Exibir miniaturas de arquivos

Tags: html, thumbnail

Alguém conhece algum plugin que permita a pré-visualização de arquivos TXT, PDF, DOC, e XLS para exibir numa página Web?

Na imagem exemplo, está sendo exibido um PDF e uma imagem

[image: Um recorte de uma página Web mostrando dois quadrados exibindo pré-visualizações de arquivos: um de um PDF e um de uma imagem]

Comment: Você consegue ser mais especifico? fale mais sobre o seu problema e compartilhe o código que você já produziu.

Comment: Na verdade Felipe, não implementei nada relacionado, não consegui e não achei nada referente. Tenho vários arquivos numa pasta, entre eles, pdf, xls, doc, jpg, png, entre outros, eu preciso exibi-los em miniatura, mostrando parte ou seu conteúdo.

Comment: +1 Acho uma boa pergunta. Eu não faço nem ideia de como fazer isso. E to muito curioso de saber como se faz. Pena que a pergunta está para ser fechada, provavelmente for falta "do que você já tentou".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cara, existe o Bootstrap File Input:

HTML 5 para Bootstrap 3.x com pré visualização para vários arquivos, oferece a seleção múltipla, e muito mais. O plugin permite-lhe uma maneira simples de configurar um controle selecionador de arquivo/upload avançado construído para trabalhar especialmente com estilos Bootstrap CSS3. Ele melhora a funcionalidade de entrada de arquivo ainda mais, oferecendo suporte para pré-visualizar uma grande variedade de arquivos, ou seja, imagens, texto, html, vídeo, áudio, flash e objetos. Além disso, ele inclui uploads baseados AJAX, drag-drop de arquivos, vendo o progresso do upload, e seletivamente a visualização, adicionar ou excluir arquivos. :

http://plugins.krajee.com/file-input

Outra opção seria utilizar essa robusta API:
http://filepreviews.io/

Começando

O serviço FilePreviews.io é composto de uma API muito simples organizado voltada para REST.

Pode ser usado para solicitar uma pré-visualização, que acontece de forma assíncrona. Os resultados retornados são úteis para diferentes cenários, permitindo que você visualize os metadados solicitados e verificar se estão disponíveis, ou utilize webhooks.

JSON será devolvido em todas as respostas a partir da API, incluindo erros.

Exemplo basico:

Código:

```
import FilePreviews from 'filepreviews'

const fp = new FilePreviews({
  debug: true,
  apiKey: 'XXXX-YOUR-SERVER-KEY-HERE-XXXX',
  apiSecret: 'XXXX-YOUR-SERVER-SECRET-KEY-HERE-XXXX'
})

const options = {
  pages: "all",
  format: "png"
}

fp.generate('https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/asTSNPAiR4qnknj7UgAP', options (err, result) => {
  if (err) throw new Error(err)
  console.log(result)
})
```

Resultado:

```
{
  "id": "46d6fbcf-83be-47ee-9eb1-2579f1d1a306",
  "url": "https://api.filepreviews.io/v2/previews/46d6fbcf-83be-47ee-9eb1-2579f1d1a306/",
  "status": "success",
  "preview": {
    "url": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/demo.filepreviews.io/dcc8ad4e46ffecf17474466cba8fa9de9c7beda2fb0518d8fe5440b4ee38db81/46d6fbcf-83be-47ee-9eb1-2579f1d1a306_original_1.png",
    "size": {
      "height": "842",
      "width": "595"
    },
    "page": 1,
    "original_size": {
      "height": "842",
      "width": "595"
    },
    "requested_size": "original",
    "resized": false
  },
  "thumbnails": [
    {
      "url": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/demo.filepreviews.io/dcc8ad4e46ffecf17474466cba8fa9de9c7beda2fb0518d8fe5440b4ee38db81/46d6fbcf-83be-47ee-9eb1-2579f1d1a306_original_1.png",
      "size": {
        "height": "842",
        "width": "595"
      },
      "page": 1,
      "original_size": {
        "height": "842",
        "width": "595"
      },
      "requested_size": "original",
      "resized": false
    }
  ],
  "original_file": {
    "metadata": {
    },
    "encoding": "binary",
    "name": "JSday Recife",
    "extension": "pdf",
    "total_pages": 1,
    "size": 39736,
    "type": "application",
    "mimetype": "application/pdf"
  },
  "user_data": null
}
```

Comment: Show de bola cara, é isso que eu quero, pena que os outros caras do forum não entendem muito e acham que não é programação. Vou começar a usar o http://filepreviews.io/. Vlw

Comment: Que pena as pessoas não tem tanta paciência....